# Variant column separate json values in file by comma?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is a basic question, I am trying to break one variant row into multiple columns and running into an error.

```html
Create or replace table App_versions(data variant); 

CREATE or Replace FILE FORMAT x_json
   TYPE = "JSON"
   COMPRESSION = "GZIP"
   FILE_EXTENSION= 'json.gz'

COPY INTO App_versions
   FROM @~/staged 
   file_format = 'x_json'
   on_error = 'skip_file';
   
 list @~;
 
 SELECT * FROM App_versions limit 10;
 
Select data:available,value::boolean as avail, data:color.value::string as col, data:name.value::string as title, data:version.value::float as version from App_versions;


Data Stored in Column

[
  {
    "available": false,
    "color": "Indigo",
    "name": "Bigtax",
    "version": "2.2.9"
  },
  {
    "available": false,
    "color": "Khaki",
    "name": "Solarbreeze",
    "version": "7.00"
  }
  ]
```

And I am running into the columns all to be Null values. What am I doing wrong? 
I based it off of:https://support.snowflake.net/s/article/json-data-parsing-in-snowflake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each `{ ... }` object to land in it's own row, then use the `STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY = TRUE` file format option.  Or you can FLATTEN() data on the fly after loading.  To access multiple objects in single row without flattening, you have to include an index to specify which object you want -- for example... `select data[0].available::boolean as avail ...`.

Comment: Select data[0]:available::boolean as avail, data[0]:color::string as col, data[0]:name::string as title, data[0]:version::string as version from App_versions; won't work for multiple. The Strip_outer_array = true worked. I changed it to: "CREATE or Replace FILE FORMAT r_json
   TYPE = "JSON"
   COMPRESSION = "GZIP"
   FILE_EXTENSION= 'json.gz'
   STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY = TRUE  and " Select data[0]:available::boolean as avail, data[0]:color::string as col, data[0]:name::string as title, data[0]:version::string as version from App_versions;

Comment: If the outer array was stripped you should be able to do `Select data:available::boolean as avail, ...` -- that is, no square brackets, since the array is gone.